# app runs fine on iphone 5 but apparently not on iphone 5S

Tags: ios7, iphone-5, c4

I just submitted my app to the app store last week and it got rejected yesterday. The reviewers apparently test on iphone 5S with iOS 7.0.4. They say the app does not load past the intro screen.

I have tested the app on iphone 5 and ipod touch 5th generation, both running the same operating system. On both it works perfectly fine.

Any ideas what could be the problem? It's a bit of an issue that I cannot test myself as the app uses the camera in the first screen and that's why immediately crashes when running in the simulator... but if I uncomment the camera setup it works in 64bit simulator...

edit:
I am using C4 for most of my interface elements. So camera init looks like this

```
cam = [C4Camera cameraWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height)];
cam.cameraPosition = CAMERABACK;
[self.canvas addCamera:cam];
[cam initCapture];
```

Comment: Your iPhone 5/iPod are they running iOS 7 ? Can you show code for presenting the camera ?

Comment: have edited the question: both devices I tested on also run iOS 7.0.4 and the camera init code is up there

Comment: Are you using the latest version of it? I'm not familiar with C4.

Comment: yes, it's the latest version. and should be fine...

Comment: suMi : Did you submitted app on appStore? I am facing same problem, how did you resolve issue.

Comment: no. C4 is not running on the latest iOS devices (iphone 5s and 5c). you need to get rid of all C4 elements in order to be able to submit to the store.... Travis might be fixing this as soon as he has the time